Elixir Phoenix live reload with multiple css files
I make use of multiple css files in the website that I'm building, but I notice that live reload works only when I modify the app.css file, while I would like for it to also work with the other css files.
This is the relevant config.exs snippet:
# Configure tailwind (the version is required)
config :tailwind,
  version: "3.4.3",
  my_dummy_website: [
    args: ~w(
      --config=tailwind.config.js
      --input=css/app.css
      --output=../priv/static/assets/app.css
    ),
    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)
  ],
  navigation: [
    args: ~w(
      --config=tailwind.config.js
      --input=css/navigation.css
      --output=../priv/static/assets/navigation.css
    ),
    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)
  ],
  home: [
    args: ~w(
      --config=tailwind.config.js
      --input=css/home.css
      --output=../priv/static/assets/home.css
    ),
    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)
  ]

the relevant dev.exs snippet:
  watchers: [
    esbuild: {Esbuild, :install_and_run, [:my_dummy_website, ~w(--sourcemap=inline --watch)]},
    tailwind: {Tailwind, :install_and_run, [:my_dummy_website, ~w(--watch)]}
  ]
...
...
# Watch static and templates for browser reloading.
config :my_dummy_website, MyDummyWebsiteWeb.Endpoint,
  live_reload: [
    patterns: [
      ~r"priv/static/(?!uploads/).*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$",
      ~r"priv/gettext/.*(po)$",
      ~r"lib/my_dummy_website_web/(controllers|live|components)/.*(ex|heex)$"
    ]
  ]

and finally the relevant mix.exs snippet:
  defp aliases do
    [
      setup: ["deps.get", "assets.setup", "assets.build"],
      "assets.setup": ["tailwind.install --if-missing", "esbuild.install --if-missing"],
      "assets.build": [
      "tailwind my_dummy_website",
      "tailwind navigation",
      "tailwind home",
      "esbuild my_dummy_website",
      ],
      "assets.deploy": [
        "tailwind my_dummy_website --minify",
        "tailwind navigation --minify",
        "tailwind home --minify",
        "esbuild my_dummy_website --minify",
        "phx.digest"
      ]
    ]
  end

I believe the problem to be the fact that, the watchers only watch my_dummy_website and therefore trigger only the my_dummy_website target in the snippet of config.exs. I think that what should be done is somehow make navigation and home dependencies of my_dummy_website, but I'm not sure how. I tried defining multiple input output pairs in the tailwind arguments but I found out that tailwind does not support that.
Does anyone know if what I'm asking for is possible? Thanks.
